# Is there a proper order to watch the DCEU movies?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, suggested-order

The MCU seems to have a well-established chronologic order to it.  I've looked up the proper order for the DCEU and there appears to be some discrepancy between some websites.

Can someone tell me, definitively, what the proper order for the DCEU is, and whether The Batman fits into the DCEU?

At the moment, I'm talking live-action feature length films only.

Comment: In this universe, like in comics, don't they invent new characters, new stories, new plots, new ennemies, new rivalry *all the time* and then they mix everything with little respect of the timeline and with more or less success? I mean, they make stories, then prequels, then spin-off then follow-ups then whatever you want to name it...

Comment: Kinda curious why 3 people down voted this...

Comment: maybe because it's opinion-based? websites disagree. Even comments below the only answer show some kind of agree/disagree, so...

Comment: @OldPadawan - A statement from DC would answer this definitively, without any need for opinion.

Answer (score 15):

Per [Odeon UK](https://www.odeon.co.uk/odeon-scene/dceu-movies-in-order/) there are basically two choices; **Release order** and **Chronological order**. Note that the 'chronological order' is basically the same as the release order, but with the two Wonder Woman films put at the front. Some flashback elements of Black Adam and Justice League take place several millennia ago, but these can largely be ignored.

> *Want to watch them in the sequence they hit the cinema? We’ve got you.
> But for the real DC connoisseur experience, why not watch all the
> movies in chronological order, following all the twists and turns of
> the DCEU timeline.*
>
> **Release order**
>
> - Man Of Steel (2013)
> - Batman V Superman: Dawn Of Justice (2016)
> - Suicide Squad (2016)
> - Wonder Woman (2017)
> - Justice League (2017)
> - Aquaman (2018)
> - Shazam! (2019)
> - Birds Of Prey: And The Fantabulous Emancipation Of One Harley Quinn
>   (2020)
> - Wonder Woman 1984 (2020)
> - The Suicide Squad (2021)
> - Black Adam (2022)
> - Shazam! Fury Of The Gods (2023)
> - The Flash (2023)
> - Blue Beetle (2023)
> - Aquaman And The Lost Kingdom (2023)

> **Chronological order**
>
> - Wonder Woman (2017)
> - Wonder Woman 1984 (2020)
> - Man Of Steel (2013)
> - Batman V Superman: Dawn Of Justice (2016)
> - Suicide Squad (2016)
> - Justice League (2017)
> - Aquaman (2018)
> - Shazam! (2019)
> - Birds Of Prey: And The Fantabulous Emancipation Of One Harley Quinn
>   (2020)
> - The Suicide Squad (2021)
> - Black Adam (2022)
> - Shazam! Fury Of The Gods (2023)
> - The Flash (2023)
> - Blue Beetle (2023)
> - Aquaman And The Lost Kingdom (2023)

---

*The Batman* will, [according to its makers](https://collider.com/matt-reeves-james-gunn-peter-safran-meeting/), not be part of the DCEU and is intended as the start of its own franchise, currently being referred to as 'the Batverse'.

Comment: I'm still looking for an "official" statement on this. There doesn't appear to be one.

Comment: One site had Black Adam between the 2 Wonder Woman movies, which didn't feel right at all.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - It's one of those situations where you have to make a judgement call. Does it re-order *the entire film* for the sake of a few minutes of flashback.

Comment: The "official" "statement" is the order in which they are released. The "official" way to consume media is always the order in which it is provided.

Comment: @OrangeDog - That isn't even close to being true. The creator of Star Wars says that you should watch them in chronological order, not release order; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112473/20774, and that's just one example. It's trivially easy to find more.

Comment: What complicates this a bit, is that [*Zack Snyder’s Justice League* \(2021\) seems to be the canon film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/276547/7957), instead of *Justice League* (2017).

Comment: @galacticninja - The Snyder Cut is [not canon](https://collider.com/is-snyder-cut-canon-dc-films-zack-snyder-comments/), but Flash has 'honored it' with some crossover stuff. Luckily nobody has watched either of them or there would be more confusion

Comment: @OrangeDog - I'm not sure how Justice League, which was released before WW84, could have happened *before* WW84.  So there's that.